# Create Sphinx nested TOC to link to a new page

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I'm trying to create a single entry on the main toctree with three nested entries that each link to a page (because our main TOC is already quite long). The structure is like this:

```
- Layers
    + Using Layers
    + Layer Arguments
    + Layers List
```

*Layers* is `layers.rst` and *Using Layers* is a heading in `layers.rst`. I created two more headings in `layers.rst` for *Layer Arguments* and *Layers List* because I want them to be on the same level. I created a toctree under the *Layers Arguments* heading, and a second one under *Layers List* so when you click on them it brings you to the TOC under each heading.

When you click *Layer Arguments*/*Layers List* I want it to go to the top of `layer_args.rst`/`layers_list.rst`, not to the heading in `layers.rst`. Is it possible to create a nested toctree that links to files in the sidebar?

Edit: Example

index.rst

```
<some headings and text>

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Layers

   layers
```

layers.rst

```
.. _using-layers:

------------------------------------------------
Using Layers
------------------------------------------------

<text>

------------------------------------------------
Layer Arguments
------------------------------------------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   Layer Arguments <layers/layer_args>

------------------------------------------------
Layers List
------------------------------------------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   I/O Layers <layers/io_layers>
   Operator Layers <layers/operator_layers>
   Transform Layers <layers/transform_layers>
   .
   .
   .
```

layers/io_layers.rst

layers/operator_layers.rst

layers/transform_layers.rst

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Sorry, I meant an example repo that I can clone. I just don't have the desire to set up a sample project from scratch.

Comment: Oh, sure- if you clone my branch you can just 'make html' in the docs directory and it should work. `git clone https://github.com/graham63/lbann.git document_layers`

Comment: Which branch? I don't see any directory `docs/layers/`.

Comment: It's the `document_layers` branch. If you use the `git clone https://github.com/graham63/lbann.git document_layers` command it will be on the correct branch

Answer (score 0):

I would move the file `layers.rst` to `layers/index.rst`, and adjust paths accordingly. Thus your directory structure and navigation structure align with one another.

### docs/index.rst

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: LBANN Layers

   layers/index
```

### docs/layers/index.rst

```
------------------------------------------------
Layer Arguments
------------------------------------------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   Layer Arguments <layer_args>

------------------------------------------------
LBANN Layers List
------------------------------------------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   I/O Layers <io_layers>
   Operator Layers <operator_layers>
   Transform Layers <transform_layers>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this doesn't seem to affect the table of contents at all. It would have the same effect as just moving `layers.rst` into the layers directory.  Clicking on the entries "Layer Arguments" and "Layers List" still just bring the user to the bottom of "layers/index.rst" instead of to the top of a landing page like when the user clicks on "Using layers." It seems clunky, but I don't think the three sections warrant space on the main TOC.

Comment: Did you try it out and compare? Make sure to do a `make clean html` to purge the cache of navigation elements.

Comment: Yeah- since the toctrees for `layer args` and `layer list` are under headings in `layers/index.rst` the link on the side bar just leads to the heading in `layers/index.rst` instead of to the pages for `layer_args` and maybe another jumping off page for `layers_list`. It's not so bad for `layers_list` because it expands the list of layers in the sidebar but it's confusing for `layer_args` that it doesn't jump to the correct page.